# How is bind_result() and fetch() able to change variables outside the scope?

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

According to this http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php bind_result should not be able to change my variables.

```
$query = 'SELECT username, status FROM table WHERE id = ?';
$id = 5;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($username, $status);
$stmt->fetch();

// Now I can use $username and $status

echo "$username has the status of $status";
```

Why is that possible, and how does this work, and how can I do this in my own php class/method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It uses [references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).

Here's an example:

```
// Notice the '&' on the 2nd param
// This is being passed in as a reference
function addToVal($val, &$ref){
    // If we edit '$ref', we are are editing the
    // variable being "referenced"
    $ref += $val;
}
```

So, then if we do this:

```
$abc = 3;
addToVal(5, $abc);
echo $abc; // 8
```

`$abc` is being updated by `addToVal` because it's being passed by reference.

Note in the docs for `bind_result` (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)

> bool mysqli_stmt::bind_result ( mixed &$var1 [, mixed &$... ] )

It says `&$var1`, that's a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Via references -!

```
function setMagically(&$ref){ 

    $ref = "Whatever value"; 

}


setMagically($someVar); 
echo $someVar;
```